# Powershell SharePoint Reporting

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

```
#SharePoint organisation name
$SP = "XXXXX"

#Variable for our connection URL
$AdminSiteURL = "https://$SP.sharepoint.com"

    
#Connect to SharePoint Admin Site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Interactive

#Listing all sites we will extract data from
$siteList = Get-PnPTenantSite

#Iterating through each site
foreach ($site in $siteList){
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url -Interactive
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Processing Site:" $site.Url
    $listLibrary = Get-PnPList -Includes HasUniqueRoleAssignments, RoleAssignments | Where-Object {$_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 -and $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $_.Title -ne "Style Library" -and $_.Title -ne "Form Templates" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets"}
    foreach ($list in $listLibrary){


        Write-Host -f Cyan "Found list:" $list.Title
        $listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $list.Title -Fields HasUniqueRoleAssignments, RoleAssignments | Where-Object {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
        $listRoles = $list.RoleAssignments


        foreach($listperm in $listRoles){
            Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $listperm -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member
            $loginName = $listperm.Member.Email
            $title = $listperm.Member.Title
            $principalType = $listperm.Member.PrincipalType
            $permissionLevel = ""




            foreach ($roleDefinition in $listperm.RoleDefinitionBindings){
                $PermissionLevel += $RoleDefinition.Name + ";"

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    "Site" = $site.Title
                    "Library" = $list.Title
                    "Item" = " "
                    "Email" = $loginName
                    "Name" = $title
                    "Type" = $principalType
                    "Permissions" = $permissionLevel
                } | Export-CSV -path C:\Users\admin\Documents\Scripts\Testreport.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
            }




            foreach ($item in $listItems){
                Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $item -Property RoleAssignments,DisplayName
                foreach($assignment in $item.RoleAssignments){
                    Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $assignment -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member
                    $loginName = $assignment.Member.Email
                    $title = $assignment.Member.Title
                    $principalType = $assignment.Member.PrincipalType
                    $permissionLevel = ""


                    foreach ($roleDefinition in $assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings){
                        $PermissionLevel += $RoleDefinition.Name + ";"
                    }


                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        "Site" = $site.Title
                        "Library" = $list.Title
                        "Item" = $item.DisplayName
                        "Email" = $loginName
                        "Name" = $title
                        "Type" = $principalType
                        "Permissions" = $permissionLevel
                    } | Export-CSV -path C:\Users\admin\Documents\Scripts\Testreport.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is intended to return a CSV with a list of SharePoint site document libraries and their corresponding user permissions, then followed by the top level folders within that library with the same data regarding user permissions.

My issue is the report runs and returns the data but seems to loop endlessly with the same information never actually breaking out and moving onto the second site/library just remaining on the one it begins with. Has anyone got a suggestion as to what is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Like more structured languages, PowerShell can create functions, modules and similar coding artefact than will help you to separate concerns. Here you have a single script that contains a single big sequence of code. You should split it into, for example, a function that extract permission for a document, a function that enumerates documents, a function that loop into lists, ... and ensure the single bricks work before assembling the whole script.

Comment: Do you have any documentation you would recommend for functions in powershell?

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you think it's stuck on the first site? What's the output it lists on the screen? Does it write many identical `"Processing Site: <siteURL>"` messages?

Comment: Level 1 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2 / Level 2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2